# Remove all slice text from Pie Chart (ios-charts/mpandroidchart)

Tags: mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I know the method for removing the x-values but how do I remove the y-values. I basically don't want ANY text on my Pie Chart.

The image shows the current-state with the 80.0 and 20.0 labels on top of the pie chart. [image: pie chart]

Comment: Which property have you used to remove x values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind figured it out!

```
pieChartView.data?.setValueTextColor(UIColor.clearColor())
```

That at least gets it from not seeing those labels.

Also another way is setting this to false:

```
drawLabelsEnabled
```

Answer (score 46):

To remove the Y-Values

Use `dataset.setDrawValues(false);`

To remove the X-Values

Use  `MyPieChart.setDrawSliceText(false);`

Comment: how can we remove or hide x values?

Comment: In ios-charts 2.1.3, `dataset.drawValuesEnabled = NO;` to hide Y-Values.

Comment: MyPieChart.setDrawSliceText(false); is deprecated, use pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false);

Answer (score 25):

> For **Charts Version 3.2.1**

**Both X - Y values enabled**

```
pieChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
pieChartView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = true
```

[image]

**To remove the Y-Values**

```
pieChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
```

[image]

**To remove the X-Values**

```
pieChartView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
```

[image]

Comment: The equivalent of this answer on Android also works.

Answer (score 7):

To remove the labels (xVals):

```
pieChartView.drawSliceTextEnabled = false
```

To remove the values (yVals):

```
pieChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 3):

`drawLabelsEnabled` will not draw any label on your chart. It is for both xAxis and yAxis

checkout for all the basic configurations:
https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/blob/master/Charts/Classes/Components/ChartAxisBase.swift

Answer (score 3):

In ios-charts version 3.1.1, you can hide piechart slice labels by setting `pie_chart.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = NO;`

Answer (score 2):

Mp Android chart,
please use this

> To remove x-Values use pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false).

> To remove y-Values use pieChart.getData().setDrawValues(false).

Answer (score 1):

In ios-charts 2.1.3, `dataset.drawValuesEnabled = NO;` to hide Y-Values.